# Reduce server response time - apache2 on debian 7

Tags: apache, seo, debian, httpresponse, httpwebresponse

I have pretty well-optimized website, PageSpeed Insights tool shows good results, **but** Google keeps saying **reduce server response time** which is 0.46 seconds. And it must not be greater than 200ms.

I have tried to delete all my htaccess content, then replace index.php with an empty index.html file, but server response remained the same. I am using a *virtual private server with Debian 7and storing 2 websites with SSL on different IP addresses.* The second site responds perfectly in 144 ms.

So, I can't find the reason why one site loads under 200ms and other in 460ms. I'm pretty sure that server has enough resources.

I would be grateful for the ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try some tweaks on your apache server. Can't guarantee that you'll get the desired result but it's an easy job and I think you have nothing to lose if you try it! So edit your apache2.conf file and adjust your actual settings to match the ones bellow (these are good settings in terms of web server security as well).

```
TraceEnable Off
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
FileETag None
HostnameLookups Off # this is important since your apache server won't try to translate your ip address into a dns name or host when you access your website

ExtendedStatus On # you can enable it afterwards, if you need it

Timeout 10
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

You could also disable apache modules (modules that you do not need or use). By default apache loads a big list of modules and I am pretty sure that you won't be needing them all. I can't provide you a list with what to keep enabled or what to disable but you can do a little Google research and based on your website you could decide what to disable and what to keep.

I am actually using all these settings on my CentOS 6.8 linux box and all the settings are in httpd.conf. On Debian you should edit **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** and maybe some other files!